# Question about url rewriting using apache mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a doubt about url rewriting using apache mod_rewrite. I am a newbie in mod_rewrite and I don't have any experience in regex.

What I want to do is to:

Rewrite **/** To **/web/content/public/**

Rewrite **/clients/** To **/web/content/clients/**

How can I achieve above things.

I tried:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   RewriteRule    ^/clients/$ web/content/clients/ [L]
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ web/content/public/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`^(.*)$` includes the slash. So don't include the slash in the rewritten pattern. 
But include a root slash at the head of your rewritten pattern.

```
 RewriteRule    ^/clients(.*)$ /web/content/clients$1 [L]
 RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ /web/content/public$1 [L]
```

Check the apache access log and error log to see what kind of request URL comes back.

Please [check the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule), especially the list labeled "Here are all possible substitution combinations and their meanings:"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/clients/$ web/content/clients/ [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ web/content/public/$1 [L]
```

And if you want to use that rules in a .htaccess file, remove the leading slash from the patterns.